# Is it possible to create an order without shipping method?

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to know if it's possible to create an order without any shipping method?

The project I'm working on requires orders without shipping method for specific products.
I first thought about creating virtual products but for now it's not an option...

Once inside the cart if there is only this specific product shipping methods would be hidden and the user could go to the next step. But I don't know if it's possible to have a quote and an order without any shipping method (and any shipping address).

This specific product is a giftcard but it can't be a virtual product (don't have a choice on this at the moment). That's why I don't want a shipping method because it will be sent by email.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hate to ask this, but as virtual products are the correct answer, why can't you use them?

Answer (score 0):

You could override Magento's logic for what constitutes a virtual product. If you override Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getIsVirtual to include a check for a specific product then essentially it will be treated as virtual.

*Usual caveat that you should extend this in your own extension rather than in core.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll give it a try and see if it could work.

Main reason why I don't use a virtual product is because the customer we have doesn't want to use them and we have to adapt to what he already has. It would be so much easier tho.

Comment: Any joy with this approach?

Comment: I'll give it a try next week and let you know how it goes :)